# Show data after AJAX call, how to render in controller?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

I would like to use `link_to` to call a controller action named show. This happens, I get a 200 message. Now I want to update a `div` with the content that is being returned.

Code in controller:

```rb
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.js 
 end
```

Code in view, link and JavaScript:

```html
<%= link_to "Show analysis", company_comparison_path(3), :remote => true , :id => "thelink" %>

<div id="replaced"> will be replaced </div>

<script>  
$('#thelink').bind('ajax:complete', function() {  
        $('#replaced').html(data)
});  
 </script>
```

I think I still don't understand how to return the HTML or JavaScript from the controller properly into the JavaScript. If I replace the word "data" in the JavaScript with some text in brackets, I get proper output. But how do I get the result from the controller action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, but you need to tell the bound function what the actual html content is you want to insert into your #results div. When you call `.html()` on `$('#replaced')` the variable you use (`data`) is still undefined.

Try the following:

```
$('#thelink').bind('ajax:complete', function(event, data) {
  $('#replaced').html(data.responseText);
});
```

edit: Oh, something to keep in mind is that this may render your view including the layout which is probably not what you want. You can add something like `render layout: false if request.xhr?` to your controller to prevent the layout from showing up on ajax requests.

Comment: This is great, solved a problem I fought with for 3 hours by now. Just wondering about the "function(event, data)" part, I think I saw this somewhere else. I need to call event as something, but I don't know what that does. Is this order fixed? Will it fail if I forget it? So happy this works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return richer content from the AJAX response, you can render the view from the controller by the :render_to_string method.

See more: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.js {
    @content = render_to_string(:partial => 'some_partial_view')
  }
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's useful. But my problem was the lack of understanding on the javascript side, which Peter solved. Still good to know.